# Drawing Dynamic Polygon through loop using data from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, drawing, polygon

I am drawing polygon from points which are retrieved from an excel sheet. There are two columns X an Y. I can plot points on the picturebox according to the X and Y coordinates from xls file; But i can't draw polygon as i don't have idea of how to make a list of points that would be available later for drawing polygon.
This application is targeted on contour generation for engineering Survey purposes. 
The code is follow. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks

```
namespace SurveyApp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult opendialogueResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (opendialogueResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }
    }
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
for (int i=1; i<=2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 2; j <= 1000; j++)
            {
                string filepath = textBox1.Text;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("" + filepath.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + "");
                Worksheet excelsheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
                int p1 =Convert.ToInt32( excelsheet.Cells[j, i].Value);
                int p2 =Convert.ToInt32( excelsheet.Cells[j, i + 1].Value);

                Graphics Contour = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                Pen pen = new Pen(brush, 1);
                //I can plot points as below
                Contour.FillRectangle(brush, p1, p2, 2, 2);
                //I need something like Contour.DrawPolygon(Parameters);
                wb.Close();
             }
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Never, __never__ do this _Graphics Contour = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();_ - You can create a valid Graphics object either in the Paint event or, maybe more appropriate here for a Bitmap : `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))...` - Also: Do collect the points into a List<Point> and feed the result into the draw/fillXxx methods as `yourList.ToArray()` ! - Also: Move the opene workbook stuff out of the loop for god's sake!

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
using OI = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
..
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
    OI.Application excel = new OI.Application();
    OI.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath, ReadOnly: true);
    OI.Worksheet excelsheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
    int row0 = 1;        
    int col0 = 1;
    int rowcount = 14;
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    for (int r = 0; r < rowcount; r++)
    {
        float x = (float) Convert.ToDouble(excelsheet.Cells[row0 + r, col0].Value);
        float y = (float) Convert.ToDouble(excelsheet.Cells[row0 + r, col0+1].Value);
        points.Add(new PointF(x, y));
    }
    wb.Close(SaveChanges: false);

    int xMax = (int) points.Select(x => x.X).Max();
    int xMin = (int) points.Select(x => x.X).Min();
    int yMax = (int) points.Select(x => x.Y).Max();
    int yMin = (int) points.Select(x => x.Y).Min();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Math.Abs(xMax - xMin), Math.Abs(yMax- yMin));

    using (Graphics Contour = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        Contour.TranslateTransform(-xMin, -yMin);
        Contour.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, Color.Black), 1.5f)
        { DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot})
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, 123, 234, 45)))
        {
            Contour.FillPolygon(brush, points.ToArray());
            Contour.DrawPolygon(pen, points.ToArray());
        }
    }
    pictureBox10.Image = bmp;
}
```

A few notes:

- Besides the obvious issue of having the workbook open inside a (double) loop I have made a few changes:
- Collect the data into a `List<T>`
- change type `int` to `float` for the data
- remove the outer loop as it only goes to the next cell
- use flexible start&stop numbers
- draw into a `Bitmap` that is displayed in the `PictureBox` at the end. If you' rather display on the pbox: move the list to class level and code the `Paint` event using its `e.Graphics` object!
- I have added the `readonly` and `savechanges` params to avoid locking the workbook and the save prompt.
- I didn't use the standard pens and brushes to show how you can achieve variations.
- I have calculated the necessary size for the bitmap from the points' data. To allow for negative values we need to translate the canvas.

You may need to set the size mode to zoom to fit the resulting bitmap into the PBox:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

You may also want to try drawing curves from the data with `DrawClosedCurve` method. Note however that this may overdraw sharp pointed portions unless you take down the `tension` paramter a lot. So you would probably extend the min/max values by an offset to all sides.

Comment: wow that was quite a work. thanks for the useful response. I am figuring out the Z axis (elevation) because i can only make a close curve for contour of nearly same Z axis values. I didnt know much of the stuff you told here. Thanks again